# Cordova Angularjs: How to get value return from CordovaSQLite

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Currently I developing cordova application by using Angularjs framework. I want to get value return $cordovaSQLite.execute() function. Usually I get the value of return by $cordovaSQLite.execute() by using .then(result()). However, the value result from .then(result()) function cannot used in outside .then(result()). Is it any solution for me to get value like result.rows.item(0).UserName; outside of my .then(result()) function. The following is my code.

```
var channelNameQuery = "SELECT * FROM chat_friend WHERE UserName=?"
var channelNamePromise = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, channelNameQuery, [channelName]).then(function (result){
        var abc = result.rows.item(0).UserName;
        console.log(abc);
})
```

Next, I try with following code to get ChannelNamePromise value. It failed to get the value.

```
var abc =  channelNamePromise.rows.item(0).UserName;
console.log(abc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

Let's just create a global method inside AppCtrl so that you can use it in multiple controllers.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope) {

        $rootScope.getFromDB = function (channelName) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var items = [];
        var query = "SELECT * FROM chat_friend WHERE UserName=?";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [channelName]).then(function (res)        
        {
            for (var index = 0; index < res.rows.length; index++) {
                var item = res.rows.item(index);
                items.push(item);
            }
            deferred.resolve(items);
        }, function (err) {
            deferred.reject(items);
            console.error(err);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
   })
```

Now in your controller

```
.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.getFromDB('yourChannelName').then(function (data) {
        console.log('Result'+data); //success block, do whatever you want 
    });
})
```

You can also assign the result to any array, like this

```
    .controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope) {

        $scope.resultArr = $rootScope.getFromDB('yourChannelName').then(function (data) {
        $scope.resultArr = result; //do whatever you want here
        });

        //outside then block you can use it.

       console.log("Result"+ $scope.resultArr);  
    })
```